# Passing commands as a string to shell sudo bash –c "ls -l /home" gives the error bash: –c: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, files, directory, ls

```
$ bash –c  "ls -l /home"
bash: –c: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I understand if you are passing commands as a string to shell then it should be able to ls right?.

Please can someone help me understand .Thank you

Comment: Your `–c` appears to contain a unicode en dash (presumably you copy-pasted the command from somewhere). Re-type it with a regular hyphen `-c`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bash` it is to execute a script

```
bash /path/to/myscript.sh
```

You don't need it to execute a command in shell, simply do

```
ls -l /home
```

The error you get is because option `-c` does not exist. 
In order to see the options of your command you can do

```
bash --help
```